# Python - How to print a name from a list corresponding to a list of numbers in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I would like to know how to print a name corresponding to a number of values in a list
for example:
I have a list with rows:

```
[['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'], [a = 2, b = 4, c = 3], [a = 8, b = 1, c = 2], [a= 3, b = 5, c= 5]]
```

and I have an if statement in my code that checks if some number is in this list

for example:

user inputs: `a = 2`, then `b = 4`, then `c = 3`

What I want is : at the end,  my code will output "Alice" cause those the values corresponding to Alice in the list

right now it prints 'yessir' as placeholder for the name

Note: a,b,c is comments added for clarification

my code:

```
from sys import argv, exit
import csv
import re
import pandas as pd

argc = len(argv)

if argc != 3:
    print("Invalid file(s)")
    exit(1)


file = open(argv[1] , "r")
file1 = open(argv[2] , "r")

text = file1.read()

strl = []
column = []

with file:

    csv = csv.reader(file,delimiter=",")

    for row in csv:
        strl = row[1:9]
        break

    df = pd.read_csv(argv[1])
    data_list = df.T.values.tolist()



for g in range(len(strl)):

    pattern = re.compile('(%s)'%strl[g])
    res = pattern.findall(text)
    repeats = len(res)
    intm = repeats


    pattern = re.compile('(%s)+'%strl[g])
    res = pattern.findall(text)
    repeats = len(res)
    intg=repeats - 1

    number = intm - intg
    if number in data_list[g+1]:
        continue
    else:
        print("No match")
        exit(1)

print("yessir")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you condense your list structure, the code becomes a lot shorter.

```
lst = [['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'], [2, 4, 3], [8, 1, 2], [3, 5, 5]]

a=2; b=4; c=3; 

if [a,b,c] in lst:
    print(lst[0][lst.index([a,b,c])-1])   # Alice
else
    print("No Match")
```

Output

```
Alice
```

Comment: Please update the question and add the correct input data

Comment: Actually nevermind , but if i have a list like this numberx = [2,4,3] instead of a = 2  b = 4  c = 3
how will go about  it? i tired replacing the [a,b,c] with numberx and it failed